# Tomcat as service unable to work with system clipboard?

Tags: java, tomcat, service

I made a password manager as java web application (Tapestry to be precise) and idea is as follows, when you click on button next to password label, the matching password should be copied to system clipboard. It works perfectly when I start tomcat the standard way (run startup.bat), but that's not what I need. I need my tomcat to start as Windows service at startup, but in this case, everything in my application works perfectly except coping to clipboard. No error occurs, nor I get anything wrong in the log, text just doesn't copy. 
Can someone tell me why is this the case, and what can cause such behavior? Can it be that service doesn't have right to mess with clipboard and if so, can I make it work?
Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When tomcat runs as a service, it does not run was a user linked to the main windows GUI, so all the awt functionalities are disabled. The only way to get some of them back is to add

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

to the tomcat startup parameters - see http://support.sas.com/kb/12/599.html
However, this may be not enough as each user has his own console, so tomcat will copy into its own user console - you should run tomcat with the same user as the local logged in user, making the "run as a .bat" the easiest option.

Comment: as a note, your type of application seems more suitably implemented with a desktop java app - normal javaSE.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me understand. I know that desktop application is more suitable but i need it to be web for more reasons, and this is only the one of its functionalities :)

Comment: What about splitting it in two components? one part desktop-based communicating with the local tomcat?so you can have the best of the two world.